# y axis in the middle of screen

Tags: android, libgdx

Hi I have a simple code:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture texture;
    BitmapFont font;
    GameObject gameObject1;
    GameObject gameObject2;


    @Override
    public void create () {


        texture= new Texture("badlogic.jpg");

        batch= new SpriteBatch();
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        gameObject1= new GameObject(texture);
        gameObject2= new GameObject(texture);
        gameObject1.x=0;
        gameObject1.y=0;
        gameObject2.x=400;
        gameObject2.y=400;
        gameObject2.height=gameObject2.getTexture().getHeight();
        gameObject2.width=gameObject2.getTexture().getHeight();
        gameObject1.height=gameObject1.getTexture().getHeight();
        gameObject1.width=gameObject1.getTexture().getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        update();
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();

        batch.draw(gameObject1.getTexture(),gameObject1.x, gameObject1.y);
        batch.draw(gameObject2.getTexture(),gameObject2.x, gameObject2.y);
        //batch.draw(texture, 0, 0);
        //font.draw(batch, "HELLO",400,400);
        batch.end();
    }
    private void update() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()){

            gameObject1.y=Gdx.input.getY();
            gameObject1.x=Gdx.input.getX();



        }
        if (gameObject1.overlaps(gameObject2)){
            Gdx.app.exit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(){
        System.out.println("dispose");
        batch.dispose();
        texture.dispose();
        font.dispose();
    }
}
```

and it's working with small problem:
y axis is in the middle screen. I'm moving finger up and object go down.
Object should bee under my finger and is like in mirror reflection.
Where is a problem?

```
private void update() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()){

        gameObject1.y=Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY();
        gameObject1.x=Gdx.input.getX();         

    }
    if (gameObject1.overlaps(gameObject2)){
        Gdx.app.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: i can't see where you are changing the x and y of `gameObject2`

Comment: gameObject2 is not moving.

Comment: oh, ok. misunderstood something. ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he is moving as a mirror as a result of: 
`gameObject1.y=Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY();` 
you got the height of the graphics, from the height you subtracted the y value of your finger. 
the y axis is in the middle so if your finger is above it, you will get negative y value. 
`newY = height-(-y) = height + y` 
the result is when oyu are moving your finger, the object moves on the y axis the negative direction to your movement.

to solve it, just switch to:
`gameObject1.y=Gdx.graphics.getHeight()+Gdx.input.getY();` 
or make the y ais in the top of the screen.

Comment: @TomaszOkraszewski any time ;)